# How to add a background and color of text to white and black respectively of nav in bootstrap when it is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a code which displays the nav. When I click on it, the background color is changing to white but the text color is not changing to black.

Here's the source code:

```
<div class="bs-example" style="padding:27px;">
    <ul  class="nav nav-tabs" style="border-bottom-style: hidden;" id="navv">
        <li><a  href="#/Home"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home ">Home</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#/Add"><span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign ">Add Form</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#/View">View Form</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.bs-example #navv li a').click(function(e) {
        var $this = $(this);
        if (!$this.hasClass('active')) {
            $this.addClass('active');
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    }); 
});
```

CSS:

```
#navv .active > a {
    color:#F95700;
}
```

I have tried like above but still the text is not getting black.

Comment: You want once first time you click it should become white and second time you click it should become black. Right ?

Comment: change #navv .active > a to #navv > a.active

Comment: @Vanojx1 has right, your css selector is not valid, in your code you gave class active to a element not li.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/RLQhh/2633/ 

once check this fiddle..And look into the nav part ..click on it.It turn to white but not the text.

Comment: Try this: `#navv li a.active {color:#F95700;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your CSS

```
#navv > a.active{
    color:#F95700;
}
```

Or script like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click','.bs-example #navv li a',function(e) {
        var $this = $(this);
        if (!$this.hasClass('active')) {
            $this.addClass('active');
            $this.css('color','#000')
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    }); 
});
```

Comment: But its not performing href link..When we click on it ,its not going to that particular specified link

Comment: Here when i make a home to active by default the color is not changing..Even if i kept id for li and make text to different color ,but the text is not changed

Comment: You can add by default active class in anchor tag #navv > li a.active{
    color:#000; }  <a class="active" href="#/Home"> and after click, first u have to remove active class from all `a` tag and add again particular one